# Weird looking Gmail location history

Tags: gmail

Starting from today the IP addresses look like this:

[image: screen shot of Gmail account activity]

So what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) IP addresses.

The IPv4 address space ran out of room some time ago. IPv6 has 7.9×10<sup>28</sup> more available addresses than IPv4, so we won't run out of addresses for quite a while.

Nothing to worry about. In fact, it's good that your ISP is finally supporting IPv6.

[image: break down of IPv6 addresses]